# Handling u'\x00' in django template

Tags: python, django

Some of the fields in my model (through a mysql db) returns a u'\x00' when accessed, and I want to detect this in a django template. Here is what I see:

```
(Pdb) patient.address.fax
u'\x00'
```

I am trying to do the following in the template ...

```
{% if person.address.fax != u"\x00"  %}
   <abbr  class="icon-print" title = "Phone"> </abbr>  {{person.address.fax}} </br> 
{% endif %}
```

I get the following error with the above template code:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '"\x00"' from 'u"\x00"'
```

Essentially, I do not want to print the fax number if person.address.fax = u'\x00'. How do I do this?

**Background:**

I export a MSSQL DB using `bcp` and import the data into MySQL. When I look at the exported data from MSSQL in emacs, I see a bunch of  "^@" (without quotes) in them. After the import this file, I suspect this ^@ shows up as \x00 (a NULL character?). There is probably some way to prevent the MSSQL from exporting this differently, but it is going to complicate things for me, and I would rather have the answer to the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in `u'\x00'` as a context variable to compare against, as in

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

from __future__ import print_function

from django.template import Template, Context
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure()

c = Context({'null': u'\x00', 'dbresult': u'\x00'})

t = Template(r"""
{% if dbresult == null %}
result is null
{% else %}
result is {{ dbresult }}
{% endif %}
""")

print(t.render(c))
```

which correctly prints `result is null`.

Comment: I really wished @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams suggestion worked, but it was more practical for me to use something similar to this method.

Answer (score 1):

1. Django's templating considers `unicode`s to be strings; you don't need the `u` prefix.
2. <s>You used the wrong charset on import; you need to set the charset to UTF-16LE first.</s>
3. `bcp` "helpfully" outputs NUL rather than an empty string in CSV where the original field is `NULL`; either tell bcp to knock it off, or perform an `UPDATE` query that sets each field to `NULL` where it's equal to `'\0'`.

Comment: (2) is a great point -- if fixing the encoding prevents there from _being_ a stray NUL, that's a huge improvement over trying to handle the case.

Comment: (2) proposes to fix the problem at the source and is an excellent idea. I tried import with CHARACTER SET utf16, and the import failed (imported just one record incorrectly with "Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns" warnings). My export command from MSSQL is bcp database.dbo.tbl_name out c:tempoutput.csv -c -t, -U user_name -P password -S server_name

Comment: You need to use `utf16le`; `utf16` is UTF-16BE.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I did try `utf16le` and I got `ERROR 1115 (42000): Unknown character set: 'utf16le'` I am using the following version of mysql: `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.29, for osx10.6 (i386) using readline 5.1`

Comment: It seems that `utf16le` wasn't added until 5.6 (/golfclap). Use `iconv` to convert the file to... UTF-8 would probably be best.

Comment: Also, how come Django isn't connecting directly to MSSQL?

Comment: `iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 person.csv > person1.csv` gives me

`iconv: person.csv:1:10774290: incomplete character or shift sequence`. Perhaps the windows export is not putting out UTF-16LE?. Also, person1.csv has tons of foreign characters. Django is not connecting to MSSQL directly because these DBs reside on client computers that I will not have direct access to. I rely of db exports that get uploaded periodically.

Comment: Would it be possible to take a look at a small piece of the file? Use [`dd`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) to slice a piece off and then zip it up so that there's no chance for anything to take "corrective" measures on the file.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and I am more than willing to learn. I did `dd if=/Volumes/temp/now/person.csv of=./person1.csv count=2` and zipped the output. Note that /Volumes/temp is a windows location mounted through samba on an osx machine (just in case these different os are causing some problems). Zip file is at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11254217/person1.csv.zip

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34810/discussion-between-trewq-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams)